# Expanding a Read more / Read less jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this great script that uses jQuery to **display a small portion of content & allow the user to read more/read less** of the content. 
Here is my current **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Tqwdh/1/

**Summary: When you click the image, it needs to reveal the additional text.**

I would love to know how I can update this script to allow the user to click the associated image and it would display more of the text (as well as keeping the text link in place).

Can someone show me how I can achieve this?

Here is my example **HTML**:

```
<article id="post-5" >

            <div class="more-less">    
                <div class="more-block">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed diam purus, lacinia eget placerat sit amet, bibendum nec nisl. Curabitur a mattis ipsum. Praesent quis nisi in purus malesuada rhoncus. Pellentesque ut quam eget libero congue lobortis. Nunc sed quam ac erat lobortis eleifend. Donec elementum sodales cursus. Aliquam porttitor massa nisi, in laoreet turpis. Sed consequat condimentum lorem ut dignissim. Sed hendrerit mauris ut massa fermentum laoreet. Pellentesque a leo vitae enim dictum lobortis. Praesent commodo feugiat velit iaculis malesuada.</p>
                    <p>Phasellus id elit ac lacus faucibus ullamcorper. Etiam ullamcorper pretium tellus, ut pharetra ante pulvinar vel. Sed neque diam, semper vel rhoncus non, congue ut sapien. Integer a mi eget libero elementum lobortis. Donec hendrerit egestas ligula sit amet eleifend. Curabitur pharetra venenatis tempor. Quisque pulvinar malesuada justo, ut euismod arcu pharetra vitae. Cras lobortis, ligula id euismod euismod, ipsum risus varius urna, faucibus gravida lectus mi nec nulla. Fusce eleifend fringilla nibh ut vulputate. Vivamus sagittis leo metus. Etiam facilisis convallis lacus adipiscing hendrerit. Duis ultricies euismod libero, nec blandit est semper a. Phasellus sit amet justo sed quam elementum lobortis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p>
                <a href="#" title="News Item 1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x187" alt="News Item 1" width="300" height="187" /></a>
            </p>            

        </article><!-- #post-## -->
```

and my **jQuery**:

```
$(function(){
        // The height of the content block when it's not expanded
        var adjustheight = 130;
        // The "more" link text
        var moreText = "Click to read more...";
        // The "less" link text
        var lessText = "Click to read less...";
        // Sets the .more-block div to the specified height and hides any content that overflows
        $(".more-less .more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        // The section added to the bottom of the "more-less" div
        $(".more-less").append('<p style="display:block;margin-top:8px"><a href="#" class="adjust"></a></p>');
        $("a.adjust").text(moreText);
        $(".adjust").toggle(function() {
                $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
                // Hide the [...] when expanded
                $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'none');
                $(this).text(lessText);
            }, function() {
                $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
                $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'block');
                $(this).text(moreText);
        });
        });
```

Thank you :-)

Comment: I really didn't understand what you actually need.

Comment: When you click the image, it would reveal the text :-) Sorry, if it was unclear.

Comment: Would make sense to let the `href` links point to the `#post-5` article instead of nowhere…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a click handler to img like this:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Tqwdh/3/)

```
$(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('article').find('.adjust').click();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Wowzer!!! Absolutely perfect. The code is so simple too - many, many thanks, roasted! You've just made my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to move the logic from the [`toggle` handler](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) to your own implementation, as you have more than one event source.

```
<article id="post-5" >
    <div class="more-less">    
        <div class="more-block">…</div>
    </div>
    <p>
         <a href="#post-5" class="adjust" title="News Item 1">…</a>
    </p>            
</article>
```

```
$(function(){
    var adjustheight = 130; // The height of the content block when it's not expanded
    var texts = {
        more: "Click to read more…",
        less: "Click to read less…"
    };
    $("article").each(function() {
        var block = $(".more-block", this).css({height:adjustheight, overflow:'hidden'}),
            cont = $("p.continue", this),
            toggle = $('<a href="#'+this.id+'" class="adjust">').text(texts.more),
            open = false;
        $(".more-less", this).append($('<p style="display:block;margin-top:8px">').append(link));
        $("a.adjust", this).click(function() {
            open = !open;
            block.css("height", open ? "auto" : adjustheight);
            link.text(texts[open ? "less" : "more"]);
            cont[open ? "show" : "hide"]();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the same behaviour of the "Click to read more" element to the image elements.

When you set the toggle handlers like this:

```
$(".adjust").toggle(function() {
        $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
        // Hide the [...] when expanded
        $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'none');
        $(this).text(lessText);
    }, function() {
        $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'block');
        $(this).text(moreText);
    });
```

Just use jQuery's [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to select the image elements also, like in this example:

```
$(".adjust, #img1, #img2").toggle(function() {
        $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', 'auto').css('overflow', 'visible');
        // Hide the [...] when expanded
        $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'none');
        $(this).text(lessText);
    }, function() {
        $(this).parents("div:first").find(".more-block").css('height', adjustheight).css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $(this).parents("div:first").find("p.continued").css('display', 'block');
        $(this).text(moreText);
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a0viedo/yHMMQ/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Many, many thanks for taking the time to put this together. I will try it out shortly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var maxLength = 50;
    $('.N_DESC').each( function (e) { 
        const thisVal = $(this).text();
        const thisLength = $.trim(thisVal).length;
        const noticeStr = thisVal.substring(0, maxLength);
        const removedStr = thisVal.substring(maxLength, thisLength);
        if(thisLength > maxLength){
            $(this).empty().html(noticeStr);
            $(this).append('<span class="more-text">'+ removedStr +'</span>');
            $(this).append(`<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="read-more" style="padding-left: 8px;">Read More..</a>`);
        }
    }); 
    $(document).on('click', '.read-more', function (e) { 
        $(this).closest('span').find('.more-text').show();
        $(this).addClass('read-less');
        $(this).removeClass('read-more');
        $(this).html('Read Less..');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.read-less', function (e) { 
        $(this).closest('span').find('.more-text').hide();
        $(this).addClass('read-more');
        $(this).removeClass('read-less');
        $(this).html('Read More..');
    });
```

```css
   .N_DESC .more-text{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="N_DESC">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci. Aenean nec lorem. In porttitor.</span>
<br>
<span class="N_DESC">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna. Nunc viverra imperdiet enim.</span>
<br>
<span class="N_DESC">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero</span>
```